# Angular: how to bind data from a service to a component so that new data in the service updates the component?

Tags: angular

When new data arrive in a service, how can I make that data appear in a component?

In my header I have a button that allows the user to switch the app between English and Spanish. The button switches the text in the header (a component) but not in the body of the view (another component).

```
ng new en-es
cd en-es
ng add @angular/material
ng generate component header
ng generate component body
ng generate service language
```

In `app.module.ts` add

```js
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

  imports: [
    ...
    MatToolbarModule,
  ],
```

In `app-component.html` replace everything with:

```js
<app-header></app-header>
<app-body></app-body>
```

In `header.component.html` replace everything with:

```js
<mat-toolbar>

  <button mat-raised-button (click)="changeLanguage('en-US')">English</button>
  <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="changeLanguage('es')">Español</button>

  <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>

  <div [ngSwitch]="displayLanguage">
    <p *ngSwitchCase="'en-US'">Hello world!</p>
    <p *ngSwitchCase="'es'">Hola mundo!</p>
    <p *ngSwitchDefault>Hello world!</p>
  </div>

</mat-toolbar>
```

In `header.component.ts` replace everything with:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LanguageService } from '../language.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  displayLanguage: string;

  constructor(
    private languageService: LanguageService,
  ) { }

  changeLanguage(language: string) {
    console.log(language);
    this.displayLanguage = language;
    this.languageService.changeLanguage(language);
  }
}
```

In `language.service.ts` replace everything with:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LanguageService {

  changeLanguage(language): Observable<string> {
    console.log(language);
    return of(language)
  }
}
```

In `body.component.html` replace everything with:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="displayLanguage">
  <p *ngSwitchCase="'en-US'">Change me into Spanish</p>
  <p *ngSwitchCase="'es'">¡Felicitaciones!</p>
  <p *ngSwitchDefault>Change me into Spanish</p>
</div>
```

In `body.component.ts` replace everything with:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LanguageService } from '../language.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-body',
  templateUrl: './body.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./body.component.css']
})
export class BodyComponent implements OnInit {
  displayLanguage: string;

  constructor(
    private languageService: LanguageService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.languageService.changeLanguage(this.displayLanguage).subscribe();
    console.log(this.displayLanguage);
  }
}
```

Spin up a server:

```
ng serve -o
```

You should see:

[image]

Click the `Español` button to change the view to this:

[image]

The language is changed in the header but in the body. The console log shows that when the app loads `language.service.ts` sends data to `body.component.ts`. Clicking a button sends data to `header.component.ts` and `language.service.ts` but not to `body.component.ts` and the body doesn't change languages.

How do I make clicking a button change the language in `body.component.ts`?

And one more thing...is there a website where I can put this software so you can easily play around with it? Plunker? I've never used those tools.

Comment: You can put the code in StackBlitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your LanguageService, create a variable with BehaviorSubject like

```
export class LanguageService {

  language: BehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('en-US');

  changeLanguage(language): void {
    this.language.next(language);
  }

  getLanguage(): Observable<string> {
   return this.language.asObservable();
  }

}
```

**body.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.languageService.getLanguage().subscribe((language) => {
    this.defaultLanguage = language; 
  });
}
```

Comment: ¡Gracias! I read several blogs about BehaviorSubject but I couldn't understand them and they didn't give working code. I'll dig into again.

Comment: I made a StackBlitz with the finished working code: https://angular-ivy-nfqqhb.stackblitz.io